# QuickTime Plugin not playing M4A (Apple Lossless Audio) Files

Tags: javascript, plugins, quicktime, lossless-compression

I'm using the Quicktime via the `QT_GenerateOBJECTText_XHTML` JavaScript call to a QT player which is controlled via the JS API. For some reason, MP3 files are beeing played just fine, but Apple Lossless (16 and 24 bit) files seem to be playing correctly (player is initalised and JS calls renturen correct values, e.g. GetDuration() returns the curret song lenght), but no sound is playing. Every other file type works just fine. This is true for Windows 8.1 with QT 7.7.6 and OS X 10.10 with QT 10.4 Dose anyone have an idea what is going on here and how to fix this?

Here is the test code I'm woring with. Test files can be downloaded at http://www.linnrecords.com/linn-downloads-testfiles.aspx for example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="playerContent">
            <object 
                classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
                width="150" 
                height="150" 
                codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=7,3,0,0" 
                id="ld_player_obj">
                <param name="src" value="/test/recit16bit.m4a">
                <param name="enablejavascript" value="True">
                <param name="postdomevents" value="True">
                <param name="autoplay" value="true">
                <param name="controller" value="true">
                <param name="loop" value="false">
                <param name="bgcolor" value="0000">
                <embed src="/test/recit16bit.m4a" width="150" height="150" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" name="movie1" id="ld_player_emd" enablejavascript="True" postdomevents="True" autoplay="true" controller="true" loop="false" bgcolor="0000">
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quicktime 7.7.6 web plugin stopped supporting some legacy codecs. If you download version 7.7.4 it should still work.

But a better solution would be to move away from plugins. Stop using Quicktime and use the HTML5 audio control instead, or have a download link to the audio file that opens up the default audio file player.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a link to the change announcements? Still not a great way to implement changes with silent fails and not explicitly failing the playback with a format unsupported message.